# Google Chrome form element reset not working

Tags: html, google-chrome, forms

I am trying to clear the values contained within a form using an HTML input type reset. It seems fine and resets the values in Safari and Firefox, just not in Chrome (Mac OSX). Does anyone know a way around this without writing javascript to do it? (I have done it this way before but want to avoid it)

```
<form ... >
   <input type="text" ... />
   <input type="reset" label="Clear" ... />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that you have your doctypes set correctly. If you are unsure about that send your HTML through the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: Guess what, it actually works... damn Chrome was being buggy. Scratch this!
Always good do run through validators though!